# Possible to use caret and lookahead in set?

Tags: python, regex

I've read the docs and looked on SO for other questions but I haven't found an answer.

Is it possible to use a lookahead within a set, or to have a lookahead be a complement within set?

I want to create a set that matches every character except for a dash preceded by a space. However, if there is only a space not followed by a dash it should be a match.

I was thinking something like this would work, but it has does not:

```
r'[^\s(?=\-)]'
```

Do lookaheads not work inside of a set? If not, how could I go about solving this problem?

Edited to provide examples:

I have been trying to find a more accurate alternative to

```
r'([^\-]*)\-(.*)'
```

Which is intended to read a line and separate artists from titles.

Applying `re.match(r'([^\-]*)\-(.*)', "artist - title")` should yield:

```
group(1) = "artist"
group(2) = "title"
```

However if the artist name includes a dash the wrong parts of the string are captured.

Example:

```
re.match(r'([^\-]*)\-(.*)', "jay-z - title")
```

Would yield:

```
group(1) = "jay"
group(2) = "z - title"
```

I want the capture group to capture spaces and dashes, but not to capture a dash if it is preceded by a space (or a space if it is followed by a dash, assuming lookahead vs lookbehind).

Comment: Could you perhaps give some examples of what you have and what to match and what shouldn't match?

Comment: updated to include examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. A character class specifies a number of possibilities to match **a single character** in the text being searched.  The lookahead and lookbehind assert conditions *around* the character you would match, but are not *part* of that character.
2. The lookahead characters **are not special** in a character class - they are treated as the literal characters. Your character class `r'[^\s(?=\-)]'` is equivalent to `r'[^\-)(?\s=]'` and means "Match every character except for =, ?, (, whitespace, and all the characters between \ and )".

For what you seem to be trying to do, try matching every character except the dash, and use alternation to get the dashes that are not preceded by space:

```
r'([^-]|(?<!\s-))'
```

*(Edited after question added examples)*

If you can trust that `' - '` always separates an artist from a song title, and will always do so on its first occurrence, you can just use the `split` method on each string, as follows:

```
>>> "jay-z - title".split(' - ', 1)
['jay-z', 'title']
>>> 'prince - purple rain'.split(' - ', 1)
['prince', 'purple rain']
>>> 'prince - purple rain - a love-song'.split(' - ', 1)
['prince', 'purple rain - a love-song']
```

`split` takes a substring on which to split, and an optional maximum number of splits to do from that string.  `split` returns the source string split into a list of substrings on the split argument, with the split argument removed.

Specifying a maximum number of splits N returns a list of N+1 substrings with the first N instances of the split target removed.  Any subsequent instances of the split target are left in place.

`split` defaults to left-to-right reading of the string, and you can get right-to-left reading of the string with `rsplit`, which also supports a `maxsplit` optional argument:

```
>>> 'prince - purple rain - a love-song'.split(' - ', 1)
['prince', 'purple rain - a love-song']
>>> 'prince - purple rain - a love-song'.rsplit(' - ', 1)
['prince - purple rain', 'a love-song']
```

The built-in string type has a lot of functionality, which you can find in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: Nice and correct answer, I wonder who and why was this downvoted.

Comment: Probably because I put a small glib answer in while I was working out the rest of it.  Should have just completed the thought before posting, rather than getting in too glib a placeholder.